# How linux can be installed on potato/toaster?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, installation, motherboard

While going over internet came across a weird post related to linux installation over at [potato](http://www.bbspot.com/news/2008/12/linux-on-a-potato.html) :

[image]

As you see over here the linus was installed over potato and it was running successfully,while digging further i came across the post which states that linux can be installed on [anything](http://gizmodo.com/5169714/how-to-get-linux-on-anything) :

After reading through this ,cant understand how the os have been installed inside such things,I googled about it but cant find any relevant information about how they did it.

did they made potato as hard disk/processing unit and proved it can be installed inside ?or all of the news were just a hoax.

Apart from the above stuff ,morning came across stackoverflow conversation which stated about same [stuff](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=26118232#26118232)

Just curious how they might installed linux over at potato any related information regarding it?

Comment: @benjaminS i cant see any relevant info bro,so is it just a hoax?

Comment: These days you could probably fit a Raspberri Pi or Arduino inside a potato. If not one of the many tiny IoT platforms. The technology used in the potato pictured above is decades out of date. PS2 port? Cardbus? C'mon, you have better hardware in an iWatch

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's way too darn funny.

Comment: @Moses yep bro,its quite funny the internet prank due to the question

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFDlVgBMomQ) could be relevant to your question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Push both the nail and the wire deep into the potato, and measure voltage output by the potato battery with a voltmeter. The produced voltage is about 0.8-0.9 volts, and 3-6 potato batteries (depending on the specifications of the LED) connected in series only produce enough current to turn on a single LED bulb , which works on low current and voltage. A small computer that is powered by a potato is a hoax.

[image]

[Potato battery driven LED](http://www.instructables.com/id/Potato-Battery-Driven-LED/?ALLSTEPS)

Comment: You didn't understand the question.  The potato is not being used as a source of power, it is the computing platform.  So your answer does NOT prove it's a hoax.  In fact it is obviously true because it was found on the Internet.

Answer (score 4):

The picture is a joke.

A potato cannot serve as a motherboard.

Linux can be installed on any computer. Some items (Microwave, Router, Car) may have a computer in them, but it is still the computer that has the OS installed on it. When people talk about a toaster running linux, they mean a toaster that is controlled by a computer, which is running Linux.

Comment: but as per http://www.bbspot.com/news/2008/12/linux-on-a-potato.html this one they were able to successfully edit the file at vim editor,how it might be possible

Comment: It's a joke, Potato's can be used as an extremely weak battery by utilizing a chemical reaction, but they cannot act as a Processor, Motherboard or any other hardware.

Comment: The potato is a lie? THE POTATO IS A LIE?!?!?!